# Is it possible to test an ASP.NET webpage or website using NUnit?

Tags: nunit, webtest

I tried using NUnit to test my ASP.NET website..but I am not able to to link the dll. It will be of great help if someone shares a small website testing example using NUnit....It will help me better if someone shares example using visual studio 2010...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awesome link that I have used with success in my tests.
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/19/unit-tests-web-code-without-a-web-server-using-httpsimulator.aspx

Comment: but on my project I have been asked to used nunit only with visual studio 2010....

Comment: Ok first i will try today and then i will contact you.

Comment: Hey I am not able to use that because I am a fresher in my team...i don't have much knowledge....It would be of great help if you could share a small web example even of a single page using that Http simulator concept....also i cannot take help from my seniors because i have been asked to learn on my own...i tried hard  but could not use that...